Computing variation of triple wedge term in Chern-Simons action
For simplicity, assume $G$ is simple, compact, connected, and simply-connected. The Chern-Simons action for a non-abelian structure group $G$ on a trivial bundle with closed base manifold is given by
$$S \propto \int_M\kappa(A \wedge dA + \frac{2}{3}A\wedge A \wedge A)$$
where $\kappa$ is the Killing form on $\mathfrak{g}$. I am trying to compute the variation of the triple wedge term $T = \frac{2}{3}(A \wedge A \wedge A)$:
$$\delta T = \frac{2}{3}\kappa([\delta A \wedge A] \wedge A + [A \wedge \delta A] \wedge A + [A \wedge A] \wedge \delta A).$$
I see that two of these terms are the same, but I keep getting that the third term is the opposite sign of the other two. In particular,
$$\kappa([A \wedge A ] \wedge \delta A) = - \kappa(\delta A \wedge [A \wedge A]) = -\kappa([\delta A \wedge A] \wedge A)$$
by symmetry of $\kappa$, cyclicity of $\kappa$, and antisymmetry of $\wedge$ counteracting antisymmetry of $[-,-]$, and
$$\kappa([A \wedge \delta A] \wedge A) = \kappa([\delta A \wedge A] \wedge A)$$
by antisymmetry of $\wedge$ counteracting antisymmetry of $[-,-]$.
However, this leads to the erroneous result that
$$\delta T =\frac{2}{3}\kappa(\delta A \wedge A \wedge A).$$
I believe that I have an incorrect understanding of manipulating these $\mathfrak{g}$-valued differential forms that is leading to this error. Hence, my question is how to correctly compute the variation of this triple wedge term.


The Lie-bracket $[\cdot,\cdot]:\mathfrak{g}\times \mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{g}$ and the Killing form $\kappa:\mathfrak{g}\times \mathfrak{g}\to \mathbb{C}$ are extended to Lie algebra-valued differential forms so that
$$\begin{align}
[A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}B]~=~&-(-1)^{|A||B|}[B\stackrel{\wedge}{,}A],\cr
0~=~&\sum_{A,B,C\text{ cycl.}}(-1)^{|A||C|}[A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}[B\stackrel{\wedge}{,}C]]
\cr 
\kappa(A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}B)~=~&(-1)^{|A||B|}\kappa(B\stackrel{\wedge}{,}A),\cr
\kappa(A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}[B\stackrel{\wedge}{,}C])~=~&\kappa([A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}B]\stackrel{\wedge}{,}C), \cr
A,B,C~\in~&\Omega(M)\otimes\mathfrak{g}, \end{align}\tag{1}$$
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the form degree.

In this answer we will work manifestly in the context of an abstract Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. the only product of Lie algebra elements that we allow is the Lie product $[\cdot,\cdot]$. E.g., we will write the Lie algebra-valued 2-form field strength as
$$ F~=~\frac{1}{2}[\mathrm{d}+A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}\mathrm{d}+A]~=~\mathrm{d}A +\frac{1}{2}[A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}A] \tag{2}$$
rather than $F=\mathrm{d}A +A\wedge A$.

The non-Abelian Chern-Simons Lagrangian 3-form is in this context
$$ \mathbb{L}~=~\kappa\left(A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}~\mathrm{d}A +\frac{1}{3}[A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}A]\right).\tag{3}$$

An infinitesimal variation is
$$\begin{align}  \delta\mathbb{L}~\stackrel{(5)+(6)}{=}~&I+II\cr
~\stackrel{(5)+(6)}{=}~&\kappa\left(\underbrace{2\mathrm{d}A +[A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}A]}_{=2F}~\stackrel{\wedge}{,}\delta A\right)\cr
&-\mathrm{d}\kappa(A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}\delta A),\end{align} \tag{4}$$
where
$$ I~:=~\kappa\left(\delta A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}~\mathrm{d}A +\frac{1}{3}[A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}A]\right),\tag{5} $$
and
$$\begin{align} II~:=~&\kappa\left( A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}~\mathrm{d}\delta A +\frac{2}{3}[A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}\delta A]\right)\cr
~=~&-\mathrm{d}\kappa(A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}\delta A)+\kappa(\mathrm{d}A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}\delta A)\cr 
&+\frac{2}{3}\kappa([A\stackrel{\wedge}{,}A]\stackrel{\wedge}{,}\delta A]).\end{align} \tag{6}$$



I updated the answer.

Would you say that $\frac{1}{2}[A \stackrel{\wedge}{,} A]$ is the right way to write down this term? As opposed to $A \wedge A$? Am I understanding correctly that $ \frac{1}{2}[A \stackrel{\wedge}{,} A] \to A \wedge A$ only when products between Lie algebra elements are defined?

$\uparrow$ Yes.
